# How can i setup read permission in spool email for root in linux

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, nagios

I am using nagios to read the file

`/var/spool/mail/root` so that i have some errors in email then know what is the problem.

I ahve setup the group to `root:nagios`

but any time when root write to that file , then it chnages the permission back to `rw-----`

i have to manually chnage it but again root chnages it back

what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Under some OS, the `/var/spool/mail` files have read permission for group `mail`, which could then be used for Nagios to access it (by placing `nagios` into the `mail` group).  However it seems that your OS does not do this.

Rather than change permissions on the file, I would suggest you instead use 'sudo'.  Add a line to your sudoers file of the form

```
nagios ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/local/sbin/mycommand
```

which will allow you to run `sudo /usr/local/sbin/mycommand` without a password as the `nagios` user.  You can then use this in your command definition or embed it into your script.